# Materialize grid s12 not working in mobile view or on Chrome's developer tools

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, web-applications, materialize

I am using materialize to do my styling and grid on the Google Web App that I am working on, but I cannot get the grid to work on mobile devices.

I did put the code suggested on Materialize documentation on my  section and as also suggested on this question [materialize grid s12 not working in mobile view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891630/materialize-grid-s12-not-working-in-mobile-view/42912833) however it is not working for me.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

What could I be doing wrong? My full HTML is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Getting started</title>
<base target="_top">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("css"); ?>

<style>
  body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #26A69A;
  }
</style>       
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col s12">
<!-- Preloader -->
       <div id='preloader' class="fade col s12"></div>
<!-- End Preloader -->
      <div class="title-text col s12" id="startingtitle">
          Select Language / Επιλογή Γλώσσας
      </div>
      <div id="themessage" class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container divblock">
            <div class="col m2 l3 hide-on-small-only"></div>
            <div class="col s6 m5 l4">
              <a onclick="gettingStarted('EN')"><div class="langselector">
                <div class="langselectorcenter">
                  <img src="<?= flagEN; ?>" class="langselectorimg"> English
                </div>
              </div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col s6 m5 l4">
              <a onclick="gettingStarted('EL')"><div class="input-field langselector">
                <div class="langselectorcenter">
                  <img src="<?= flagEL; ?>" class="langselectorimg"> Ελληνικά
                </div>
              </div></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m2 l4 hide-on-small-only"></div>
          </div> <!-- closing container -->
        </div> <!-- closing row -->
      </div> <!-- closing themessage -->

      <div class="bottom col s12">
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - you are not using the grid markup correctly. If you follow the guidelines from the documentation, you'll see that responsive grids are made up of three elements, nested in a very particular way:

**1. Container**

This is the outermost element and everything sits inside it. You can have one per page, or one per section, depending on the design, but very rarely would you have a container inside a row or a col. It's name suggests what it does - it contains the content, ie, sets a maximum width that it can be:

Mobile: 90%

Tablet: 85%

Desktop: 70%

**2. Row**

Rows sit in containers. They span the container, have a margin bottom for spacing, and are used to group columns.

**3. Col**

Cols sit inside rows, and these are the actual element that has media query styling to provide responsiveness:

s12 = take up 12 columns (half the space) at all screen widths

s6 = take up 6 columns (half the space) at all screen widths

m6 take up 6 columns (half the space) at tablet width

l6 = take up 6 columns (half the space) at desktop width

You can nest rows inside cols to provide nested grids, but it is very rarely needed - you can use flexbox for spacing inside cols.

The structure is very simple but very specific:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         [content goes here]
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         [content goes here]
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have built a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/XWboZdE) demoing the basics, and added border to each of the element so that you can see how much space each ones takes.

https://materializecss.com/grid.html

Comment: Thank you so much... silly me! Just realised my structure!

Comment: do you know if Google Web Apps are responsive? I made several pages where the responsiveness is working on codepen but not on Google Web Apps! Could I be doing something wrong? An example is this [link](https://codepen.io/mikechris/pen/GRpggwb)