# Unable to List the materialize css cards in the same row

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, materialize

I am making a webpage where i fetch movies using an api and i am trying to list the movie posters using the materilize css card in the same row, but it only gets listed on top of each other as a column.

app.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={};


        this.performSearch()

    }

performSearch(){

$.ajax({
url:urlString,
    success:(searchResults) =>{
    console.log("Feteched succesfully");
    //console.log(searchResults);
    const results = searchResults.results
        //console.log(results[0])
    const movieRows = [];

        results.forEach((movie) =>{
           // console.log(movie.title);
            console.log(movie.poster_path)
            const movieRow =   <MovieLists movie={movie}/>
            movieRows.push(movieRow);
        })

        this.setState({rows:movieRows})
    },
    error:(xhr,status,err) =>{
    console.error("Failed to fetch");
    }
})
}


    render() {


        return (
            <div className="App">

                {this.state.rows}

            </div>
        );

    }
}

export default App;
```

MovieLists.js

```
 <div className="container">
         <div className="row">
             <div className="col s12">

                     <Movie key ={props.movie.id} image={props.movie.poster_path}
                     title={props.movie.title}/>




             </div>
         </div>

     </div>
```

Movie.js

```
<div className="col s12 m6 l3">

        <div className="card" >
        <div className="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-dark">
            {
                props.image == null ?
                    <img src ={'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarket.ionicframework.com%2Fstarters%2Fomdb-search&psig=AOvVaw3Beb0rUUVxt3OsEfwzu07Q&ust=1585542435018000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJj8kIPsvugCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD'}
                         alt="card image"
                         style={{width:"100%",height:360}}/>
                         :
                <img src ={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185${props.image}`}
                alt="card image"
                style={{width:"100%",height:360}}/>
            }
            <div className="card-content">
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

The movieLists component lists the movie component on top of each other, i am trying to find the way to list them horizontally responsively.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to always use the correct grid structure, which is:

.container > .row > .col

All cols MUST sit in rows to behave responsively. Adding a .row div around the movie.js output will fix your problem.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         [content goes here]
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         [content goes here]
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See this answer from yesterday:

[Materialize grid s12 not working in mobile view or on Chrome's developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887593/materialize-grid-s12-not-working-in-mobile-view-or-on-chromes-developer-tools/60899170#60899170)

Codepen with a single .row div to fix your problem (note I've had to chnage className to class):

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/eYNbwOQ

https://materializecss.com/grid.html